# .htaccess custom RewriteRule for Symfony2

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I need to maintain the mapping of old urls in a new Symfony2 application, (without redirection). But I'm going crazy on the RewriteRule...

I just want something really simple:
Supposed the public url domain.tld/info-cookies.html should be mapped to a specific route let say domain.tld/information-cookies

I have the following rewrite:

```
RewriteRule info-cookies.html$ /app.php/informations-cookies [NC,L]
```

But no matter what we try, we can't succeed to achieve this.
I am missing something there ?

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: it goes to another controller matching the pattern /{xxx} where xxx caught is info-cookies.html

Comment: Is the rewrite rule is above other rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the noise, it was the path_info which is not taking in account by Symfony2 ;) Only the real url...